# AddSwaggerGen - create object in swagger.json for not used DTO

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-codegen

I use `services.AddSwaggerGen()` to create a swagger.json:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.CustomOperationIds(apiDesc => {
        if (apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out var methodInfo)) {
            if (methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HttpMethodAttribute)).FirstOrDefault() is HttpMethodAttribute attr) {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attr.Template)) {
                    return attr.Template;
                }
            } 
        }

        return $"{apiDesc.HttpMethod.Substring(0, 1)}{apiDesc.HttpMethod.Substring(1, apiDesc.HttpMethod.Length -1).ToLower()}";
    });

    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo() {
        Title = "Time API",
        Version = "v1",

       });
});
```

This is working so far. But now, I have a DTO, which is not used explizit in a Controller. And this DTO is not added as an object to the swagger.json. Is there a possibility to configure, that this DTO will also be included in the swagger.json?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add an attribute to the DTOs that are not referenced elsewhere.
Please follow the [documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#enrich-schema-metadata) by just adding the package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` and then adding to your DTO the `SwaggerSchemaAttribute` as follows:

```cs
[SwaggerSchema(Required = new[] { "Description" })]
public class Product
{
    [SwaggerSchema("The product identifier", ReadOnly = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [SwaggerSchema("The product description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [SwaggerSchema("The date it was created", Format = "date")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Please notice that it is a good practice to describe controllers and models with attributes as they will be added to the embedded webpage as well as in your `swagger.json` file